# Vuejs onclick data redirection in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js

Is it possible in Visual Studio Code, in .vue files to Ctrl+Click on a function or data to redirect to the function / data ( maybe there are an extention to do this ) ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/886Kz.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible :)

1.Install the extension called 'Vetur'.
2.In your settings.json, add the following:

```
"vetur.experimental.templateInterpolationService": true
```

My settings.json is located in ClientApp/.vscode/settings.json . Your path may be different.
You should now be able to click on any function etc. and it will redirect you to it in your script.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJQykqGl2xs&ab_channel=GoCode-WebDevelopersMentoring

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that is a different error. It looks to me like the object 'user' doesn't have a type, or isn't defined properly (that is why it is of type unknown), but I can't help because I can't see enough of your code.
If you post a new question with more of your code someone will be able to help.

Comment: I solved it by opening the project where is the package.json outside of the folder, thanks.